# Flattening nested JSON column in pandas dataframe while making duplicates of other features

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

Essentially, I have a data with fields  that look like this:

Text_ID:    1

Title: Theory of Theories

Abstract: Text Example

Year: 2019

Authors: [{'First_Name':'George','Last_Name':'Washington','Affiliation':'USA']},[{'First_Name':'Bill','Last_Name':'Buttlicker','Affiliation':'CAN']}

What I am attempting to do is flatten the nested JSON list under Authors into the dataframe, but I'd like to keep it where while George Washington USA has his own row including Text_ID, Title, Abstract, and Year, Bill Buttlicker CAN has the same data for his own row, and I've been struggling to figure out how to flatten/normalize in such a manner.

I have attempted json_normalize, some json_flatten UDFs, flattening and re-appending, etc... to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The below seems to work

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Text_ID': 1, 'Title': 'Theory of Theories', 'Abstract': 'Text Example', 'Year': 2019,
        'Authors': [{'First_Name': 'George', 'Last_Name': 'Washington', 'Affiliation': 'USA'},
                    {'First_Name': 'Bill', 'Last_Name': 'Buttlicker', 'Affiliation': 'CAN'}]}
normalized = []
for auth in data['Authors']:
    normalized.append(auth)
    normalized[-1].update({k: v for k, v in data.items() if k != 'Authors'})

df = pd.DataFrame(normalized)
print(df)
```

output

```
  First_Name   Last_Name Affiliation  ...               Title      Abstract  Year
0     George  Washington         USA  ...  Theory of Theories  Text Example  2019
1       Bill  Buttlicker         CAN  ...  Theory of Theories  Text Example  2019

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I attempted using this on my data frame (just to make sure I'm clear, authors is a nested json column in a pandas DF) and it returns "'list' object has no attribute 'update'", so I am unsure how to resolve this

Comment: I based the solution on the data you have posted. It works. If the actual data is different - how do you think we can help you?